# rails 3 email question: how to get /usr/sbin/sendmail executable file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

in rails 3 **sendmail_settings**, there is a option `:location` which represent the location of the sendmail executable (Defaults to **/usr/sbin/sendmail**). In my ubuntu OS machine, there is no such file under **/usr/sbin**, how can I get **/usr/sbin/sendmail** executable then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override options for the :sendmail delivery method then you can use sendmail_settings. You can override these setting in your environment file.

```
config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
  :location => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
  :arguments => '-i -t'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install sendmail-bin.  You should have done a search using a package manager. It's ubuntu.. Also it looks like gzipped executables can be found all over the web.